# Is there a name for deriving exponential growth at a point?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, exponential-function, regression

I've been messing around with exponentials lately, and an interesting question I asked myself was, is it possible to calculate the exponential growth at a point?

So, I'm sure you're familiar with derivatives and tangents. With a derivative if you have $f(x)$, and $f'(x)$ is constant from $a$ to $a+1$, then $f(a+1) = f(a)+f'(a)$

Now, let's say we have some function $f(x)=2^x$ where the rate of growth is constant(100% growth every unit), now let's say $g(x)$ will be our equation to describe exponential growth at each point. Since it's constant throughout, $g(x)=2$ at all times. You can then say that, if $g(x)$ is constant from $a$ to $a+1$, then $f(a+1) = f(a)*g(a)$

I've been able to calculate that $$g(x)=exp\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)$$
Now, this is very interesting, and even somewhat useful to me especially for regression, since exponential growth rates do in fact change a lot in the real world. And you can either solve $g(x)=exp\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)$ as a differential equation on a case by case basis to get the exponential for a specific growth function, or use the more general integral, particularly if you want to compute it numerically: $$f(x)=c_1exp\left(\int_1^xln(g(t))dt\right)$$

Explanation aside, my question is does $g(x)$ have a more formal name, and where are some places where I can learn more about, or see such math being used?

Edit:
After a brief discussion in the comments, I have realized I need to make more clear what exactly g(x) is doing, so I will write, in order, that $$g(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \sqrt[h]{\frac{f(x+h)}{f(x)}} = exp\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)$$
And that in a similar to which $f(x+h)\approx f(x)+f'(x)*h$, $$f(x+h)\approx f(x)g(x)^h$$

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what exactly you mean by $g$, or even what you mean by growth rate. Because $f$ is not growing at a constant rate if it is exponential. Do you mean something like "if $f$ grows then $f'(x) = g(x) f(x)$ for some function $g(x)$ and $g$ is constant??

Comment: @memerson I guess I could have been more clear, but it was pretty hard to articulate from the beginning. Pretty much with g(x) it's a derivative, but instead of describing linear growth, it describes multiplicative growth. The basis is that for any equation $f(x)=a^x$, the growth rate is constant, hence: $g(x)=a$, and then expanding this out to the idea of "what if g(x) wasn't constant, but instead different at each point?"

Comment: It seems like the best way to make this concept of "multiplicative growth" is that it is somehow related to $f'(x)/f(x)$? If we reverse engineer from the equation $g(x) = \operatorname{exp}(f'(x)/f(x))$ then $g(x) = \ln(f'(x)/f(x)$ which seems to be something like what you want. Would you be willing to take this as what you mean by "multiplicative growth"?

Comment: @memerson I think you're still missing the picture. Think back to basic exponential models where you have $a * b^t$, b is your rate of growth, which is constant. It's just that, but dynamic. Also, $g(x) \ne ln(f'(x)/f(x))$ as you mentioned. I believe what you meant to do was $ln(g(x))=f'(x)/f(x)$. Think of g(x) like this: with a normal derivative, you add, with g(x), you multiply. It's the same exact concept, but for two different operations, to represent important information about specific functions.

Comment: It's still not clear what the "rate of growth" is for a general function.  We have the definition of something for exponential functions. We say that the rate of growth of some exponential function $f(x) = b^x$ is defined to be $b$. Ok, that's great. Then what is the exponential growth of $g(x) = e^{\sin(x)|\tan(1/x) + 5x^2$. The answer isn't well defined because we haven't defined what we mean by growth rate for non-exponential functions. It also isn't clear what special property the growth rate has that you are trying to preserve  so how should we know how to extend.

Comment: For example, you say that what you mean by growth rate is something akin to "multiplicative growth." So we want to approximate $f$ "multiplicatively" but what does that mean? Do we want that $f(x+h) \approx f(x) *g(x)^h$? Do we want that $f(x*h) \approx f(x)g(x)h$, or many others. Is $g(x)$ the base of the "exponential which best approximates $f$ at $x$ whatever that means? The problem is that it isn't clear what $g$ is supposed to map onto for a general function, unless it is simply $exp(f'(x)/f(x))$.

Comment: Let me drop that $g(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\sqrt[h]{\frac{f(x+h)}{f(x)}}$ and consequentially, $f(x+h)\approx f(x)*g(x)^h$ I suppose looking back, I probably shouldn't have skipped the step of calculating $g(x)=exp(f'(x)/f(x))$ from $g(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\sqrt[h]{\frac{f(x+h)}{f(x)}}$, and frankly it wasn't until you mentioned f(x+h) equations that even realized I hadn't explicitly stated so already. I mostly have myself to blame for not taking good notes.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. When I tried to come up with a definition mine was slightly different, ($f(x+h) \approx f(x) * e^{k(x) h}$), which is related to yours by $g(x) = e^{k(x)}$. As far as where this function might be used, I haven't seen it anywhere (although that certainly doesn't mean it's not used). It seems like it could have some interesting properties, and I would find it useful to understand "what kind of growth is happening." I wish I could've been more help!

Answer (score 1):

After discussing what the operation I was doing really meant in the comments, a new name hit me, multiplicative derivative, and after a quick google search, it turns out the exact thing I have described does in fact already exist and has been written about! It has been coined the term "Multiplicative calculus" by others, and many papers seem to have been written with it. I will post just one, below. The symbol commonly used for it is $$f^*(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{f(x+h)}{f(x)}\right)^{\frac{1}{h}}=e^{\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}}$$

similar to how I had already described. Regardless of ending up just answering my own question, hopefully this can serve as a gateway for anyone who was also curious of similar things to find the term they may have been looking for, and thanks to @memerson in particular for our discussion in the comments, which led to me discovering the name.

https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81954511.pdf